Taking many attributs from Yolo result
I want to take some attributs from Yolo result, this is the code.
from ultralytics import YOLO
from datetime import datetime

model = YOLO("yolov8n.pt")
source = "https://youtu.be/LNwODJXcvt4"
results = model(source, stream=True)

for result in results:
    if result[0] is not None:
        with open("result.txt", "a") as myfile:
            for idx, coordinate in enumerate(result[0].boxes.xywhn):
                dt_now = datetime.now()
                date = f"{dt_now.year}-{dt_now.month}-{dt_now.day}"
                time = f"{dt_now.hour}:{dt_now.minute}:{dt_now.second}:{dt_now.microsecond}"
                cls = int(result[0].boxes.cls[idx].item())
                path = result[0].path
                class_name = model.names[cls]
                conf = int(result[0].boxes.conf[0]*100)
                
                myfile.write(f"Name: {class_name} ({cls}),\nConfidence: {conf},\nCoordinate: [{coordinate[0].item()} {coordinate[1].item()} {coordinate[2].item()} {coordinate[3].item()}],\nDate: {date},\nTime: {time}\n\n")

i just want to ask is this good or there is some useless code? this to complecated for me to read

Looks fine to me. I can't test it because of I can't connect to the source but if it works for you the code lokks good !

@TheGovernor the source is youtube, u just need to install ultralytics, its works, i am just asking is there redundant program that i can remove because there is to much nested, for inside with inside if inside for

I know but I am getting a connection error. Anyway all the nested is required. Since you are using a video as a source results should be a list containing the predictions/detections for each frame in the video. So for each frame, if there is something detected, for each object detected, you assign the different variables and write the class the confidence, the coordinates etc... to a file

If you're looking for a code review you should ask on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/
Stack overflow is not for opinion based questions

I added some comments for each nested block to help you understand what each one is for:
from ultralytics import YOLO
from datetime import datetime

model = YOLO("yolov8n.pt")
source = "https://youtu.be/LNwODJXcvt4"
results = model(source, stream=True) # should be a list of the results obtained for each frame in the video

for result in results: # for each frame
    if result[0] is not None: # if the model detected some objects
        with open("result.txt", "a") as myfile: # with this file opened
            for idx, coordinate in enumerate(result[0].boxes.xywhn): # for each detected object (actually for its index et its box coordinates) on the frame
                dt_now = datetime.now() # get the current time
                # format the date and time to be written on the file 
                date = f"{dt_now.year}-{dt_now.month}-{dt_now.day}"
                time = f"{dt_now.hour}:{dt_now.minute}:{dt_now.second}:{dt_now.microsecond}"
                cls = int(result[0].boxes.cls[idx].item()) # the class of the detected object (as an integer value)
                path = result[0].path # not quite sure what this is
                class_name = model.names[cls] # the name of class of the detected object
                conf = int(result[0].boxes.conf[0]*100) # the confidence score
                
                # writing all the above to a file
                myfile.write(f"Name: {class_name} ({cls}),\nConfidence: {conf},\nCoordinate: [{coordinate[0].item()} {coordinate[1].item()} {coordinate[2].item()} {coordinate[3].item()}],\nDate: {date},\nTime: {time}\n\n")

